# Howto create an windows 10 application which starts a Self-Hosted website without IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, webserver

I want to create a small windows 10 application where the user can start and add a single file (f.e. via drag and drop0. This file can then be downloaded in the local network as long as the application remains open.

I am now looking for the best way to do this, without using IIS. I have no idea where to start so I would appreciate any input. As far as I can tell .Net Core with Kestrel is a good way to go.

Comment: This is most likely what you're looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.2. As far as the Windows 10 app goes, you're just going to use a web view, basically to connect to this.

Comment: So in this case I would completely separate the UI from the actual webserver, and I could also use any implementation for the UI as long as I implement the connection to the service, right?

Comment: Well, I suppose it depends on how you want to set it up. I think my mind just instantly went to doing it as a web application, but your self-hosted website could just be a simple API, and your Win10 app would just communicate with that under the hood and handle the UI however it likes.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to have Drag-and-Drop functionality, you'll either want to accept a file dropped onto an `.exe` file, or have a Windows Forms or WPF app that can accept a file drop.

Either way, you can start an ASP.NET Core `WebHost` with Kestrel enabled from within any of these solutions, as long as it is running on a thread separate from the UI thread (the `Run()` method will block).

Comment: So in terms of starting point, I should look out for a tutorial covering ASP.NET Core WebHost with Kestrel?

Comment: Yeah; follow some basic ASP.NET Core starting tutorials, and then play around with your `Program.cs` file to get a feel for how you could start the `WebHost` from another application.